# Upload pdf file and automatically create list columns in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, pdf

My requirement is :

When a user uploads a pdf file into a document library. There is a table in a pdf file which two columns. The SharePoint should understand and create list columns from the first column in the pdf file and the second column in the pdf file are the list items in the SharePoint list.

Is there any simple out of box method in SharePoint which does that?

Comment: Please specify - is it pdf form or just simple scanned to pdf format file?

Comment: It is a PDF form.